# REST - tricky example when POST doesn't always create new resource

Tags: rest

In my REST service I have an endpoint `POST /api/images` to add new images. But I don't want to add the very same image multipe times, so after each *POST* call I compute the hash of the content to check if it already exist in my database - if it is, then I don't add it once more but just return the ID of previously uploaded one.

How does it fit into REST best practice where it clearly states that after using `POST` brand new resource should be created? Obviosuly it's against it but I can't see better alternative here `(*)`. Not sure if I even should bother, but I would love to read some options on this.

`(*)` The alternative which would probably satisfy all REST purist would be to redsign: when adding new image, I should first call `GET /api/images` to find out if the image with given content already exists, if so - return it, otherwise call `POST /api/images` which would always add new resource. BUT that would require 2 HTTP calls - is it worth it? Especially that we are sending quite big requests (images).

Comment: Hmm, this is tricky. POST is the right verb to add new elements, but it's also not supposed to be idempotent. You're effectively wanting to add an element to a *set*, where assuming equality is sane, it is idempotent.

Answer (score 0):

> How does it fit into REST best practice where it clearly states that after using POST brand new resource should be created?

It fits just fine

1. In HTTP, POST doesn't mean "create a resource", it means [process the enclosed representation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3).  The semantics are deliberately very broad.

It may help to remember that the reference application for the REST architectural style is the world wide web, where POST is the only unsafe method available via HTML forms.

2. HTTP constrains the [semantics](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-tag/2002Apr/0207.html) of the request, *not* the implementation.

> I don't want to add the very same image multipe times

Right - [idempotent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2) request handling is a good idea.  You aren't forbidden from using idempotent handling of POST requests.  Clients aren't allowed to *assume* that your handling will be idempotent, but you are still allowed to do it.